# ISO App crashes intermittently on device as well as simulator

Tags: ios

We built an app using Appcelerator framework. It crashes intermittently.

In crash dump, I can find following error:

Application Specific Information:

> Assertion failed: (self.url != nil), function -[APSHTTPRequest send],
>   file
>   /Users/hknoechel/Documents/appcelerator_modules/APSHTTPClient/APSHTTPClient/APSHTTPRequest.m,
>   line 78.

any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It gives you an error message, a file, and a line number. Did you look at this file and try to debug?

Comment: @Neeraj it seems a url passed nil, this is an assertion crash so is in your APSHTTPRequest  library check the line 78 in APSHTTPRequest.m

Answer (score 0):

I guessing the file APSHTTPRequest.m is not opening due to the file path /Users/hknoechel/Documents/appcelerator_modules/APSHTTPClient/APSHTTPClient/APSHTTPRequest.m being incorrect.